# Js обращение к объекту через его значение

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив let array = [];
я его заполняю вот такими объектами
let object={
id:0,
x:100,
y:100
}
Можно ли как-то обратится через его id , а не по индексу

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Логичнее уж сразу заполнять не массив а объект: `let object = {}; object[0] = {x : 100, y : 100}; ...; console.log(object[id]);`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться методом **[find](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** у массива:

```js
 let array = [
    { id:0, x:100, y:100 },
    { id:666, x:666, y:666 }, 
    { id:999, x:999, y:999 }, 
];

let searchId = 666;
let result = array.find(el => el.id === searchId);
console.log(result);
```